# dynamically position element with Less

Tags: css, less

I have a div (div1) that shows up on hover of another div (div2) to the right and to the bottom of it (sort of like a tool tip). When the div2 happens to be too close to the bottom of the screen, div1 obviously goes off the screen (completely or partially). Is there a way to position div1 to the top of div2 depending on where div2 is located and do it purely with Less, no JavaScript. Maybe some other ways, but without JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: Is div1 height dynamic?

Comment: yes in terms that it depends on how much text goes into it, but I don't assign it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

With pure css it will not be possible at current moment. Still you can do it without javascript. But it will be very ugly and not reliable. So consider my next line more like sport interest than actual advice. Than you can achieve it so:

1. Determine on server side how much space is there between div2 and the end of html content. Make sure to get as much data from client device as you can (like width and height) somehow from user agent and consider them in your calculation.
2. Calculate the sizes of your div1. It will be a bit easier, i think.
3. Generate appropriate css